# Was my home's dormer flashing installed incorrectly?

Tags: roof, waterproofing, water-damage, flashing

I've lived in this home for two years now. Roof is probably at least 10-15 years old, perhaps 20 years.

We started noticing some water stains on the ceiling soon after moving in. On a closer look, it seemed like the previous owner painted over prior stains to hide them, so this may have been an issue for a long time. It only seems to worsen when we have a very heavy storm.

[image]

Fortunately there is a crawl space close to the issue, but unfortunately I can only see a portion of the area where water is seeping in. The area that looks bad is right where the front of the dormer is (window side).

The other dormers on the roof also seem to have the same moisture issue within the crawl space (though not bad enough to cause issues with the ceiling).

[image]

When inspecting the issue from the roof side today, the only obvious issue observed was that J channels on the dormer sides were clogged up with dirt and some moss growth (cleared prior to the picture).

[image]

Red area in the image shows where we have definite water issues, orange area is unknown (no crawl space access).

All of the roofing guides I've read show that the dormer flashing should have been done differently. The flat portion should be four inches away from the sides (it's at most 2 inches for ours), and the apron should be covered by shingles on the sides (not on top).

[image]

[image]

Since they did not follow the regulation on the above items, it also makes me suspect other issues that may exist under the roofing. Perhaps the underlayment does not run along the wall of the dormer.

Comment: I use a FLIR camera to pinpoint leaks, sometimes the leak can be a long distance away from the point the leak shows up. You are probably correct on the location

Comment: What is with the cardboard? Covering up issues?

Comment: The cardboard already existed when we moved in. I presumed it was either to keep insulation against the roof or as a weak insulator? Just my guess. All of the crawl spaces have it.

Comment: As far as the cardboard up against the bottom of roof, you need to remove that and any insulation that is in there, insulation should be on attic floor after laying down a vapour barrier. And you need proper ventilation in there as well.

Comment: @jpcooler I’ve since moved from this house.  While I would’ve insulated it the way that you mentioned, the only real downside to doing it, the way shown above is that it allows the creation of ice dams.  However, that can be mitigated with a snow rake.